# Multi-Part answers for a node in IBM Watson Conversation service

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, chatbot, watson-conversation

I would like to be able to split up an response into multiple messages that are sent in a row - e.g. "Hi, i am a chatbot", "What can i do for you?" as 2 separate messages (that a client would render individually)
Is there a way to do this without separate child-nodes?
e.g.

```
{
  "output": {
   "text": {
   "append": true,
     "values": [
        "Hi, i am a chatbot",
        "What can i do for you"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "chained" response? Could you provide formatted output of what it should look like?

Comment: Basically 2 (or more) successive messages that the client would render individually ("message bubbles"). When i understood data_henrik correctly, i could achieve this by using \n as signal for the middleware to split the message

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
  {
  "output": {
    "text": [
       "Hi, i am a chatbot",
        "What can i do for you"
    ],
    "selection_policy": "sequential"
  }
```

}

Remove Values from the json.

Comment: hm, not sure how i overlooked this, but thank you very much!

Comment: and you can also use <br> to split the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean with "chained response" several messages that are printed below each other, you can simply use `\n` to denote a carriage return:

```
{
  "output": {
   "text": {
   "append": true,
     "values": [
        "Hi, I am a chatbot.\nWhat can I do for you?"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
}
```

This would render to:

```
Hi, I am a chatbot.
What can I do for you?
```

I have a couple such reponses in this [workspace](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/slack-chatbot-database-watson/blob/master/conversation-workspace.json). It is part of this [tutorial for building a database-backed Slackbot](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html). In that example, several of those output lines are computed dynamically and would, e.g., produce a formatted ASCII table.

Comment: `append` default is `true`